# jqplot - set custom color for bar charts based on label name

Tags: backbone.js, jqplot

I have a backbone app that dynamically renders multiple bar charts with different data sets and I have no way of knowing which label name will show up. For example, if given a set of labels: "strawberry", "vanilla", "chocolate", I would like to set the color for "strawberry" to pink every time that category shows up in a graph.

Is there a way to set a specific color on a bar based upon its label value?

Here is my current code:

```
collectCategories: function(aggregates) {
  var categories = {};
  _.each(aggregates, function(aggregate) {
   for (var category in aggregate) {
    categories[category] = true;
  }
});
  categories = _.keys(categories);
  categories.sort();
  return categories;
},

render: function() {
  var container = this.$el;
  container.empty();

  var aggregates = this.collection.map(function(purchase) {      
   return purchase.aggregates();
  });

 var categories = this.collectCategories(aggregates);

 var datasets = _.map(categories, function(category) {
 var row = _.map(aggregates, function(aggregate) {
  var qtyInCategory = aggregate[category];
  return qtyInCategory ? qtyInCategory : 0;        
});
  return row;          
});

var labels = this.collection.map(function(purchase) {
  return purchase.get('purchase_date').substr(0, 10);
});

if (datasets.length > 0) {
  this.renderPlot(datasets, labels, categories);
}
return this;
},

renderPlot: function(datasets, labels, categories) {
var seriesLabels = _.map(categories, function(category) {
  return { label: category};
});

var customSeriesColors = 

var plot = $.jqplot('bar-charts-container', datasets, {
  stackSeries: true,
  captureRightClick: true,
  seriesDefaults:{
    renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
    rendererOptions: {
      barMargin: 30,
      varyBarColor: true  
    },
    pointLabels: {        
      show: false
    }
  },

series: seriesLabels,

seriesColors: 

axes: {
  xaxis: {
      renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
      ticks: labels
  },
  yaxis: {
    padMin: 0
  }
},

legend: {
  show: true,
  location: 'e',
  placement: 'outside'
}      
});
```

Comment: It doesn’t look like jqPlot supports that, but it seems likely that there’s a way to catch the label names somewhere in your Backbone code and add custom colours based on the labels. Hard to say without seeing the code where you construct the plot.

Comment: Thanks Buck, my code is now up.  Perhaps the logic should be placed in "customSeriesColors" under "renderPlot" and then passed to "seriesColors" (also under property "renderPlot")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have access to your labels when you plot, why not just define the colours there too?

```
seriesColors: colorsForLabels(seriesLabels)
```

Elsewhere in the object:

```
colorsForLabels: function(labels) {
  return _.map(labels, function(labelObj) {
    switch (labelObj.label) {
      case 'strawberry':
        return 'pink';
      case: 'vanilla':
        return 'white';
      default:
        # return a random colour from a list
    }
  });
}
```

The `default` is an open question; if you *could* have labels that don’t match the predefined list, you’ll have to choose from a list of alternates.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The code is in place however, would you by any chance know why this is logging in my console: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of undefined "?  It seems like the graph is only rendering the last case statement.

Comment: Where does the error happen? What happens on that line?

Comment: The problem is solved, minor mistake on my part where 'label' should be 'category' instead. thanks!